# Function takes too much time to process in loop from database(3000 times)

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am calling a function in loop of 3000 time . I am calling that function and getting some dictionary from that function but it takes time . I am fetching data from database which gives me approximately 3000 rows and i am looping that rows and calling function in that loop which fetch data from database and returns dictionary but it takes time .

**Code:**

```
def test(request, uni_id):
    try:
        Obj = get_object_or_404(tabl_name, id=uni_id)
    except:
        Obj = None

    dict = {}
    if Obj:outlet_info
        dict['data1'] = Obj.id
        dict['data2'] = Obj.name
        dict['data3'] = Obj.eg
        dict['data4'] = Obj.access

    return dict  


cursor.execute('''SELECT cd.name, cd.no,ofk.demo_id
                    FROM `main_table` as myo 
                    LEFT JOIN `table1` as emt ON emt.some_id = myo.some1_id
                    LEFT JOIN `table2` as ofk ON ofk.id = myo.kit_id
                    LEFT JOIN `table3` as cd ON cd.eg_id = myo.eg_id
                    WHERE emt.type='test''''

result = dictfetchall(cursor)
tmp_list, tmp_dict = [], {}
for res in result:
   tmp_dict['name'] = res['name']
   tmp_dict['no'] = res['no']
   info = test(request,res['demo_id'])
   tmp_dict['data1'] = info['data1']  
   tmp_list.append(tmp_dict.copy())
```

Here I am getting `demo_id` from query and passing that to another query using function `test` to fetch data therefore it is taking too much time .

Can anyone tell me how to improve the speed or include `demo_id` to main query and fetch data from main query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included all the things in query. now i don't need to call function `test`

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT (SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',id,name,eg,access) 
                from tabl_name where id=ofk.demo_id) AS result 
                ,cd.name, cd.no,ofk.demo_id
                FROM `main_table` as myo 
                LEFT JOIN `table1` as emt ON emt.some_id = myo.some1_id
                LEFT JOIN `table2` as ofk ON ofk.id = myo.kit_id
                LEFT JOIN `table3` as cd ON cd.eg_id = myo.eg_id
                WHERE emt.type="test" '''
result = dictfetchall(cursor) # function to get data in form of dictionary
tmp_list, tmp_dict = [], {}
for res in result:
    try:
        info = res['result'].decode("utf-8").split(",") # converting res['result'] from bytes to string 
    except:    
        info = res['result'].split(",") # res['result'] is in string form
   tmp_dict['name'] = res['name']
   tmp_dict['no'] = res['no']       
   tmp_dict['data1'] = info[0] # id 
   tmp_list.append(tmp_dict.copy())
```

This thing makes my code 10 times faster

Answer (score 2):

You are making 3000 db calls(by calling `get_object_or_404` 3k times) that is definitely going to slow. Instead you should try fetching objects via `tablemanager.filter(id__in=id_list)`. Prepare id_list in loop and pass that list to your test function.

Comment: also if you need only few fields try using `.values(id,name,eg,success)`. That would be memory efficient.

Comment: **@sachin dubey** alternative, if you could build that entire logic into `SQL`-*query* itself, that would be great too: just fire a single query and get final results (no intermediate processing required from your side) *[I haven't been through your query and code thoroughly, so can't say if that's even possible]*

Comment: Ya i am trying to do that too @y2k-shubham

Comment: I did that and that works amazingly . thanks for the suggestion @y2k-shubham

Comment: There are 3000 IDs approx. to filter currently. The thing to note: divide and process your results into chunks, use LIMIT & OFFSET otherwise application may run out of memory on a large scale with limited resources.